# Jsoup: How to convert a String containing HTML to a XHTML document?

Tags: java, html, parsing, xhtml, jsoup

Title says it all. How to do that with Jsoup? I don't need a file. Just XHTML to use. I've only found some examples with bytearrays and fileoutputs. I only need a valid XHTML to use with itext PdfWriter and XMLWorker later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe something like this would do the trick

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.xhtml); //This will ensure the validity
doc.outputSettings().charset("UTF-8");
System.out.println(doc);
```