# Parsing XHTML with Jsoup 1.11

Tags: java, html, xhtml, jsoup

I am trying to parse a XHTML file with Jsoup and its stripping the closing slash on  some of my tags. ie:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/assessment.css" />
```

becomes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/assessment.css">
```

I have tried some of the other answers here:

[Jsoup: How to convert a String containing HTML to a XHTML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28876603/jsoup-how-to-convert-a-string-containing-html-to-a-xhtml-document)
https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/511
[jsoup: differnt result after updating from 1.7.3 to 1.8.1, how to avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881191/jsoup-differnt-result-after-updating-from-1-7-3-to-1-8-1-how-to-avoid-this)

With my latest attempt being:

```
    File input = new File("src\\main\\resources\\templates\\assessmenttemplate.html");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "");
    doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.xhtml);
    doc.outputSettings().charset("UTF-8")
```

I also tried to change the doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

But the problem persists. How to parse HTML without stripping the trailing slashes?

Answer (score 2):

This worked:

```
    File input = new File("src\\main\\resources\\templates\\assessmenttemplate.html");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "");
    doc.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);
    doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.xhtml);
    doc.outputSettings().charset("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Yep that works! Give yourself the answer!